# How to pass parameter as POST data on selection of an Select Box value, which will reload the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I had two chained Select Boxes "pr_cat" and "sl_num" . The second select box values depend on the value selected in the first select box.

```
<tr>
    <td width="257">Select Product Category:</td>
    <td width="197">
        <select name="pr_cat" id="Validprcat" onChange="reload(this.form)"><option value="">< Select one ></option>
        <?php while($prd=mysql_fetch_object($select_query1)) { 
        if ($prd->cat_id==$pcat) { ?>
    <option selected value="<?php echo $prd->cat_id?>"><?php echo $prd->category_name?> </option>
    <?php } else { ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $prd->cat_id?>"><?php echo $prd->category_name?></option>
      <?php }}?>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Select Serial Number:</td>
    <td>

    <select name="sl_num"  id="Validslnum" onChange="reload2(this.form)"><option value="">< Select one ></option>
        <?php while($slnum=mysql_fetch_object($quer)) { 
              if ($slnum->serialno==$pcat2) { ?>
    <option selected value="<?php echo $slnum->serialno?>"><?php echo $slnum->serialno?> </option>
    <?php } else {
     ?>

        <option  value="<?php echo $slnum->serialno?>"><?php echo $slnum->serialno?></option>
        <?php }} ?>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
```

I used the form reload javascript to reload the page with the value selected in the Select Box. I used GET method.

```
<script language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.pr_cat.options[form.pr_cat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
self.location='delivery.php?pcat=' + val ;
}

function reload2(form)
{
var val=form.pr_cat.options[form.pr_cat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
var val2=form.sl_num.options[form.sl_num.options.selectedIndex].value; 
self.location='delivery.php?pcat=' + val + '&pcat2=' + val2 ;
}
</script>
```

But I want to do it using POST method how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ajax, and do it via POST method, so instead of

```
 onChange="reload(this.form)"
```

call

```
 onChange="formSubmit();"


<script>
function formSubmit()
{
  document.getElementById("frm1").submit(); //frm1 is form id
      //OR you can use
  //document.frm1.submit(); //frm1 is form name
}
</script>
```

Note :- if you have any submit button in this form, don't keep it's name as submit, else you will have issues in your code.

Comment: While you code is correct, But Note part is confusing, How submit button name will generate problems :)

Comment: only if you name the submit button as name='submit', you can get issues, it has happened with me twice, and after renaming the button, it works fine.

Comment: This should not happen as submit button name will not reflect any problem. I myself have habit for using submit as submit button name and never encountered any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is pretty much this: [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

However, why do you want to reload the page at all instead of doing an AJAX call?

Comment: i want to do it AJAX also but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I give you the most simple and fastest way to do what you wanted,

AJAX:

cover both select box with '' tag,

```
<div id='first_select'>
   <select id='first' onchange='populate_second_select(this.value)'>
   <option>Select</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div id='second_select'>
   <select>
   <option>Select</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

call `populate_second_select()` function upon change done in first select box.
No in ajax,

```
function populate_second_select(value)
            { 

                $.ajax({
                                method:'POST',
                                url:'ajax.php',
                                data: {value:value},
                                success:function(result)
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("second_select").innerHTML=result;
                                    showLightBox();
                                }
                            });
            }
```

This is how your javascript function should look like,

on your ajax.php file, process the DB based on chosen value and '**echo**' the whole select tag (second tag). That's it.

Here are few links would help you to get this done.

[Link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036821/jquery-ajax-using-ajax-to-populate-select-boxes-in-a-dynamic-form)[Link_2](http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/)